# Can't install zip on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, zip, dependencies

I'm trying to install the zip package on my ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS server, but when I run the command `apt-get install zip` I get the following output

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic but it is not going to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried to run `apt-get -f install` but it fails because there's no available sapce on the boot disk, I think it wants to install the new 18.04.2 LTS release. But I don't want to update the Ubuntu release, I just want to install the zip package, what can I do?

Comment: You say it tells there's no available space on `/boot/`. You can try to free space there by removing previous kernels.

Comment: it could help, but I don't want to update my kernel. Do you think `apt-get -f install` will update it?

Comment: I think `apt-get -f install` would update it, if `/boot/` had enough space. You can add space to `/boot/` by: (1) cleaning it from garbage (but it's unlikely that is there any garbage there), (2) expanding `/boot/` in order to fit your new kernel (but I don't know if you are running LVM, so am not sure how feasible is at your host), (3) using `apt` to purge any potential previous kernel **not the exact which you are running**.

Comment: You can also cancel the kernel update. I know how to do that in `aptitude`. Unluckily, I don't know how to do that without using `aptitude`.

Comment: Maybe you can cancel the kernel update easily from whatever GUI facility to deb packages they ship nowadays.

Comment: Once your kernel update is canceled, you are able to run APT installs without hassle.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to resolve the kernel update before you are able to run any other `apt-get install`.

You have several ways out of there:

1. If you have any garbage in `/boot/` remove them. But it's unlikely you have any garbage there.
2. Maybe (specially if you are using LVM?) you can extend the `/boot/` partition to accomodate the new kernel image.
3. You can cancel the kernel update. There are many ways to do so.

   - E.g. Ctrl-T (Actions menu) > "Cancel pending actions", for `aptitude` users.

---

Next time you want to use a high level package manager, instead of `apt-get`. Makes easy to unbreake conflicted situations like yours and even much more complicated than yours.

Cheers,

Comment: Is there a way to install zip "manually"?

Comment: Of course. What did I do? Go https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages, search "zip", from the results linked to https://packages.debian.org/buster/zip, from there linked to http://infozip.sourceforge.net/Zip.html, and there you can surely find prebuilt binaries and for sure you can find a link to the source code, then download, and follow README or INSTALL instructions in order to build it from source. Almost every time these steps are fruitful.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!